# Iframe renders outside foreignobject tag within svg

Tags: object, iframe, svg, rendering

see underneath code. the iframe content renders outside the box, how can I fix this? Thanks in advance

```
<svg class=imac viewBox="0 0 4182 3461" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="Mac" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="iMac-27-inches" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-409.000000, -270.000000)">
        <g sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(409.000000, 270.000000)">
            <g id="Body" transform="translate(0.000000, 2489.000000)" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup">
                <path d="M1577.64,971.42 C1505.81,971.42 1459.903,966.251 1455.929,955.691 L1455.929,941.928 L2726.059,941.928 L2726.059,955.691 C2722.085,966.251 2676.178,971.42 2604.348,971.42 L1577.638,971.42 L1577.64,971.42 Z" id="Leg-Front" fill="#D5D2CF"></path>
                <path d="M1575.87,959.63 C1517.429,959.63 1456.947,956.394 1455.935,941.935 C1466.604,920.26 1602.695,849.688 1620.41,817.781 C1646.689,783.33 1664.504,545.619 1676.143,389.447 L1676.143,385.515 L2505.859,385.515 L2505.859,389.447 C2517.498,545.619 2535.313,783.33 2561.592,817.781 C2579.307,849.688 2715.398,920.26 2726.067,941.935 C2725.055,956.394 2664.573,959.63 2606.132,959.63 L1575.872,959.63 L1575.87,959.63 Z" id="Leg" fill="#C3C3C3"></path>
                <path d="M4182,0.14 L0,0.14 L0,290.438 C0,345.077 44.36,389.438 99,389.438 L4083,389.438 C4137.64,389.438 4182,345.077 4182,290.438 L4182,0.14 L4182,0.14 Z" id="Body1" fill="#D5D2CF"></path>
                </g>
            <g id="Screen" fill="#343434" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup">
                <path d="M4182,99 C4182,44.36 4137.64,0 4083,0 L99,0 C44.36,0 0,44.36 0,99 L0,2493.08 L4182,2493.08 L4182,99 L4182,99 Z" id="Black-Frame"></path>
                <path d="M4015.5,164.974 C4015.5,163.319 4014.156,161.974 4012.5,161.974 L169.5,161.974 C167.844,161.974 166.5,163.319 166.5,164.974 L166.5,2327.974 C166.5,2329.63 167.844,2330.974 169.5,2330.974 L4012.5,2330.974 C4014.156,2330.974 4015.5,2329.63 4015.5,2327.974 L4015.5,164.974 L4015.5,164.974 Z" id="Screen-Frame"></path>
                <rect id="Screen1" x="171" y="166.5" width="3840" height="2160"></rect>
                <foreignObject x="171" y="166.5" width="3840" height="2160">
                <iframe xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" src="http://test.nl" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
                </foreignObject>
            </g>
        <circle id="Camera" fill="#3E3E3E" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" cx="2091" cy="68.815" r="17.695"></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[see Example (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW3VZ.png)

Iframe is on the right place within the svg. However, it's content just offsets down and to the right. Besides that, the width and height set to the iframe (which also are OK according to the svg), are not honored by the iframe content...

***UPDATE***:

I found out that when I use test.nl as src of the iframe, the iframe content is misplaced. However, when I use another link, such as 123test.nl then I get the iframe to render correctly. So, what could be wrong with the home script of test.nl to cause this render problem?

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems fine to me on Firefox.

Comment: @RobertLongson, indeed. I have tested it after your comment in firefox and it rendered well. So, why does it render wrong on chrome and safari? (The image I uploaded is made in safari)

Comment: Raise bugs on their bugtrackers perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt to place your Iframe at the centre of the foreignObject it's convenient to specify the same width="3840" and height="2160" as the foreignObject,

Comment: The width and height attributes in percentages are relative to the foreign object element. This works fine, since the Iframe is exact the same width and height as the foreign object. However, the iframe start on x=171 and y 166.5 (obviously of course), however the iframe content start with higher x and y values and I can't see why